# DispHTMLTableCell.childNodes[0].textContent evaluates to null in IE8 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code to populate an array.

```
matches = $('.cultureShortNameColumn');
numMatches = matches.length;

cultures = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numMatches; i++) {
  cultures[i] = matches[i].childNodes[0].textContent;
}
```

This code works perfectly in FireFox, Chrome and IE 9 and above.

However, in IE 8 and below, I see in the debugger that, the following expressions evaluate as follows:

```
matches[i]                          {...}   DispHTMLTableCell
matches[0].childNodes                   {...}   DispDOMChildrenCollection
matches[0].childNodes[0]            {...}   DispHTMLDOMTextNode
matches[0].childNodes[0].textContent    undefined   Undefined
```

However, when I expand the `matches[0].childNodes[0]` local variable in the Watches window in the debugger, it does have a `textContent` property that reads a valid value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did a small bit of googling after posting this question and there's an answer right there in the top links:

The answer is to use `nodeValue` instead of `textContent`.

I tried it and it works.

```
matches[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```